# Failed to read serial number(ASN1_INTEGER) from x509 certiticate using openssl

Tags: openssl

How to read certificate details ( serial number, issuer , subject details) from x509 certificate using Openssl.

I parsed P12 file using PKCS12_parse(), then retrieved serial number in ASN1_INTEGER format from objtained x509 certificate. But how do I parse it so that it can be read.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes I could retrieve few details of Certificate along with serial number, issuer and subject details.

Comment: how did you get the serial number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this way.. and could read the values of certificate.

```
   bio_out=BIO_new_fp(stdout,BIO_NOCLOSE);   //here instead of stdout, a file pointer can also be given
   x509 = sk_X509_value(certs,0);
   X509_NAME_print_ex(bio_out,X509_get_issuer_name(x509), XN_FLAG_COMPAT, X509_FLAG_COMPAT);


//Issuer Name
BIO_printf(bio_out,"\n");
unsigned long nmflag = 0;   
CryptoUtility *cryptoU = [[CryptoUtility alloc] init];
[cryptoU print_name:bio_out title:"Verify : issuer= " x509name:X509_get_issuer_name(x509) flag:nmflag];
BIO_printf(bio_out,"\n");

//Subject Name
BIO_printf(bio_out,"\n");
[cryptoU print_name:bio_out title:"Verify : subject= " x509name:X509_get_subject_name(x509) flag:nmflag];
BIO_printf(bio_out,"\n");

//Serial NO
BIO_printf(bio_out,"\n");
BIO_printf(bio_out,"Verify : serial=");
i2a_ASN1_INTEGER(bio_out, X509_get_serialNumber(x509));
BIO_printf(bio_out,"\n");
BIO_printf(bio_out,"\n");
//NSLog(@"Issuer name %@",X509_get_issuer_name(x509));

    //Common Name
char peer_CN[256];
X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID(X509_get_subject_name(x509),NID_commonName, peer_CN, 256);
NSLog(@"Verify : comman name %s",peer_CN);
```

I hope this would help.

Comment: instead of File pointer how to get the value from the BIO structure ..? I want to use Memory Bio structure. instead of file BIO structure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a memory BIO:

```
 BIO *mem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
 //pass this mem BIO to hold the data

 Extract the BUF_MEM structure from a memory BIO and then free up the BIO:

 BUF_MEM *bptr;
 BIO_get_mem_ptr(mem, &bptr);
 BIO_set_close(mem, BIO_NOCLOSE); /* So BIO_free() leaves BUF_MEM alone */

 char *buff = (char *)malloc(bptr->length);       //converting BUF_MEM  to Char * 
 memcpy(buff, bptr->data, bptr->length-1);        //to be used later as you needed
 buff[bptr->length-1] = 0;
 NSLog(@"--------------------------->%s",buff);
 BIO_free(mem);
```

buff can be used in the logic further....Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi @Balamurugan, These are my first answers, why dont you please accept them if they really help you